# Put object request in AWS S3 Kotlin SDK fails for big files because of timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3

I try to use AWS SDK for Kotlin to put file in Yandex Object Storage (S3 Storage from Yandex). Following example on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/kotlin_s3_code_examples.html I wrote this:

```kotlin
package org.example

import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.s3.S3Client
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest
import aws.smithy.kotlin.runtime.content.asByteStream
import aws.smithy.kotlin.runtime.net.url.Url
import java.io.File

suspend fun main() {
    val putRequest = PutObjectRequest {
        bucket = "my_bucket"
        key = "file.mp3"
        body = File("file.mp3").asByteStream()
    }

    S3Client.fromEnvironment {
        endpointUrl = Url.parse("https://storage.yandexcloud.net/")
        region = "ru-central1"
    }.use { s3 ->
        val response = s3.putObject(putRequest)
        println("Tag information is ${response.eTag}")
    }
}
```

This works well for files about 1MB and smaller. But for 2.5MB and bigger files I got

```
Exception in thread "main" aws.smithy.kotlin.runtime.http.HttpException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout; HttpErrorCode(SOCKET_TIMEOUT)
    at aws.smithy.kotlin.runtime.http.engine.okhttp.OkHttpEngine.roundTrip(OkHttpEngine.kt:158)
    at aws.smithy.kotlin.runtime.http.engine.okhttp.OkHttpEngine$roundTrip$1.invokeSuspend(OkHttpEngine.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.kt:704)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.kt:713)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:150)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:96)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:111)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:51)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:65)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at aws.smithy.kotlin.runtime.http.engine.okhttp.MetricsInterceptor.intercept(MetricsInterceptor.kt:30)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:205)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:537)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
    Suppressed: okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: CANCEL
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:157)
        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:96)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:111)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:95)
        ... 16 more
```

This seems to be client-side error, as Yandex has no limit to file size. Any files are easily uploaded in Yandex Cloud Console.

I tried to look through fields of `PutObjectRequest` and `S3Client.Config.Builder` but found there nothing about timeout or max file size.

The alternative variant is to use Amazon S3 REST API directly, but would be better to find out a solution for Kotlin SDK.

Get object requests work well for all files. I uploaded some files up to 600MB through online console and they were loaded by get requests and didn't fail with timeout, though requests took some time. Only put object get this error.

Comment: I changed s3 storage to VK Cloud and everything works. So, that's problem with Yandex Storage